# How to display each file in its own li tag only in react javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, antd

I am working on a project that uses react and javascript and ant design.
There is a problem in this part that I have shown.
I want when I add a file via an input, a li will be displayed only inside the .showFile environment.
But here it is displayed in all li.
But I want, for each li, to display its own file separately.

For example, when I add a file to the first li, it starts to appear inside the second and third li and .... .
The send button is the same. When one of them is clicked, all of them perform the sending process.

Can you guide me, how can I fix this problem?

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Upload, Col, List } from "antd";
import { UploadOutlined, SendOutlined, DeleteOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import { persianToEnglishNum } from "../../../helpers";
import "./styles.css";
import { AnswerServices, StudentsServices } from "../../../api/services";
import { strings } from "../../../common";
import { message } from "antd";
import { BASE_URL, PROTOCOL } from "../../../api/api";
import { useRedux } from "../../../hooks";

const HomeworkBox = () => {
  const [allHomeworks, setAllHomeworks] = useState([]);
  const [filesArray, setFilesArray] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [selectedHomeworkId, setSelectedHomeworkId] = useState(null)
  const { Get } = useRedux();
  const { studentId } = Get().user;
  const homeworkId = selectedHomeworkId;
  
  console.log('filesArray :>> ', filesArray);

  const getTodayHomeworks = async () => {
    await StudentsServices.getTodayHomeworks(studentId).then((res) => {
      if (res) {
        setAllHomeworks(res);
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getTodayHomeworks();
  }, [])

  const badRequestRequest = (err) => {
    if (
      err.response &&
      err.response.data.message === "The assignment delivery date has been completed."
    ) {
      setLoading(false);
      message.warning(strings.fa.endDeliveryData);
    }
  };

  function DataURIToBlob(dataURI) {
    const splitDataURI = dataURI.split(",");
    const byteString =
      splitDataURI[0].indexOf("base64") >= 0
        ? atob(splitDataURI[1])
        : decodeURI(splitDataURI[1]);
    const mimeString = splitDataURI[0].split(":")[1].split(";")[0];

    const ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++)
      ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);

    return new Blob([ia], { type: mimeString });
  }

  const getBase64 = (blob, filename, homeworkId) => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    reader.onload = function () {
      const file = DataURIToBlob(reader.result);
      let permission = true;
      for (let perFile of filesArray) {
        if (perFile && perFile.file && perFile.file.filename === filename && perFile.homeworkId === homeworkId ) {
          permission = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (permission) {
        setFilesArray((prev) => [
          ...prev,
            {
              homeworkId: homeworkId,
              file: {
                filename: filename,
                data: file,
              }
            }
        ]);
      }
    };
    reader.onerror = function (error) {};
  };

  const onFileChange = (selectedFile) => {
    getBase64(selectedFile.file.originFileObj, selectedFile.file.name, homeworkId);
    console.log('homeworkId onFileChange:>> ', homeworkId);
    console.log('selectedFile onFileChange:>> ', selectedFile);
  };

  const sendFiles = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    let requestStatus = "success";
    const formData = new FormData();
    
    for (let perFile of filesArray) {
      const homeworkId = perFile.homeworkId;
      const fileExtension = perFile.file.filename.split(".").pop();
      if (
        fileExtension === "mp3" ||
        fileExtension === "aac" ||
        fileExtension === "amr" ||
        fileExtension === "wma"
      ) {
        formData.append(
          "audio_file",
          perFile.file.data,
          `${perFile.file.filename}.${fileExtension}`
        );
      } else if (
        fileExtension === "jpg" ||
        fileExtension === "jpeg" ||
        fileExtension === "png" ||
        fileExtension === "pdf" ||
        fileExtension === "doc" ||
        fileExtension === "docx" ||
        fileExtension === "mp4" ||
        fileExtension === "avi"
      ) {
        formData.append(
          "file",
          perFile.file.data,
          `${perFile.file.filename}.${fileExtension}`
        );
      }      
    }

    const res = await AnswerServices.addAnswer(
      formData,
      studentId,
      homeworkId,
      { baseURL: `${PROTOCOL}${BASE_URL}api/v2/parent/` },
      { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
      badRequestRequest
    );
    if (!res) {
      requestStatus = "failed";
    }

    if (requestStatus === "success") {
      setFilesArray([]);
      setLoading(false);
      message.success(" Your file has been sent successfully ");
    }
  };


  const removeFile = (index) => {
    setFilesArray((prev) => {
      let newfileArray = [...prev];
      newfileArray.splice(index, 1);
      return newfileArray;
    });
  };

  const propss = {
    name: "file",
    onChange(info) {
      onFileChange(info);
    },
    progress: {
      strokeColor: {
        "0%": "#108ee9",
        "100%": "#87d068",
      },
      strokeWidth: 3,
      format: (percent) => `${parseFloat(percent.toFixed(2))}%`,
    },
  };

  const handleClick = (id) => {
    setSelectedHomeworkId(id);
    console.log("setSelectedHomeworkId id :>> ", id);
  };

  return (
    <div className="homework-container">
      <ul className="homeworks-list">
        {allHomeworks && allHomeworks.length !== 0 &&
          allHomeworks.map((item) => {
            let { id, course, homework, homework_delivery_on, homework_files } =
              item;
            return (
              <li key={id}>
                <h3 className="course">{course.str}</h3>
                <p className="homework-send">
                  <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>User Homeworks</span>:{""}
                  {homework}{" "}
                </p>
                <p className="homework-send">
                  <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                    {" "}
                    delevery day {" "}
                  </span>
                  : {homework_delivery_on}{" "}
                </p>
                <p className="homework-attachments">
                  {homework_files && homework_files.length !== 0 && (
                    <>
                      <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}> attachment :</span>
                      <br />
                    </>
                  )}
                  <div className="attachment-btns">
                    {homework_files &&
                      homework_files.length !== 0 &&
                      homework_files.map((file, index) => {
                        let idx = index + 1;
                        let num = persianToEnglishNum(idx.toString(), true);

                        return (
                          <>
                            <Button>
                              <a
                                href={file.file}
                                target="_blank"
                                rel="noreferrer"
                              >
                                {` MyFile ${num}`}{" "}
                              </a>
                            </Button>
                          </>
                        );
                      })}
                  </div>
                </p>
                <div className="upload-files-homework">
                  <Upload
                    showUploadList={false}
                    {...propss}
                    onClick={() => handleClick(id)}
                    onChange={onFileChange}
                  >
                    <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Select File </Button>
                  </Upload>

                  <Button
                    className="send-homework-btn"
                    loading={loading}
                    disabled={filesArray.length === 0}
                    onClick={sendFiles}
                  >
                    <SendOutlined /> Send
                 </Button>
                </div>
                <Col xs={24} xl={24} className="showFile">
                  <br />
                  {filesArray && filesArray.length !== 0
                    ? filesArray.map((i, index) => {
                      console.log('i :>> ', i);
                        if(i && i.file.filename){
                          let filenameLength = i.file.filename.length;
                          console.log('filenameLength :>> ', filenameLength);
                          return (
                            <>
                              {i.file.filename && (
                                <div style={{ marginBottom: " 0.5rem" }}>
                                  {" "}
                                  <List style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>
                                    {filenameLength === 37 &&
                                    i.file.filename.slice(
                                      filenameLength - 1,
                                      filenameLength
                                    ) === "k"
                                      ? `file voice ${persianToEnglishNum(
                                          (index + 1).toString(),
                                          true
                                        )}`
                                      : i.file.filename}
                                    <a
                                      onClick={() => removeFile(index)}
                                      style={{
                                        float: "left",
                                        color: "red",
                                        cursor: "pointer",
                                      }}
                                    >
                                      <DeleteOutlined
                                        style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}
                                      />
                                    </a>
                                  </List>
                                </div>
                              )}
                            </>
                          );
                        }
                      })
                    : ""}
                </Col>
              </li>
            );
          })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomeworkBox;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the shared state of `filesArray`, it's used in all li tag.
You need to manage the file state independently for each homework item.

Separate your code into multiple components like HomeWorkItem, FileUpload ...

Note: Please try to follow idiomatic approach